# pip installing local package for testing in sibling folder

Tags: python, pip, python-unittest, setuptools, setup.py

I have source code I want to test in a test folder that is a sibling to the src code folder. see structure below

```
├── src
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── module1
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── somecode.py
│   │   └── module2
│   └── setup.py
└── tests
    └── test1.py
```

my setup.py file looks like this

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="src_code",
    version=0.26,
    description="solves relative imports",
    author="yer boi",
    url="",
    package_data={"": ["LICENSE"]},
    package_dir={"": "modules"},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="modules"),
    python_requires=">=3.8",
    py_modules=[
],
)
```

right now i have a .venv active and i am runing `pip install -e src` from the base folder to have a local editable package i can test and import into the tests folder/files. The problem is when i pip freeze I am getting some weird string in what has been installed and I cannot import any of my locally built packages. pip freeze looks like the following

```
black==22.10.0
-e git+https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git@5da71eb9ecb1cb08c930edd1d052fa209375f38d#egg=src_code&subdirectory=lambdas
```

Any one know why I am getting this strange pip freeze result, and how to fix this so I can locally build and import my src package?

my top_levell.txt file in src_code.egg-info looks like this

```
module1
module2
```

Comment: Does that not work?  That's just embedded the version as a github commit identifier.

Comment: @TimRoberts no unfortunately it doesn't :( when I try and import from the locally installed package in the tests file it has no auto complete, and says it doesn't exist when run

Comment: This layout looks all wrong. The `setup.py` is not supposed to be in `src/setup.py`, rather `src` and `setup.py` should be at the same level.  And what is the point of the extra "modules" subdirectory?

Comment: @wim so i thought the `package_dir={"": "modules"}` would point to the directory modules and then all the top level (module1, module2) would then be importable. These things are working if i push them to a private code artifact repository, but for local -e development they are not working. I'm not trying to create a code artifact for this package because it is only for running unit tests. I have the same problem when the `setup.py` file is a sibling to `src`  and set `package_dir={"": "src"}`

Comment: @wim also i appreciate the help, been spinning on this problem for a while now

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was taht i was doing `pip install -e /path/to/package`. This was creating some problems with importing for some reason, the links to the egg-info files seemed off. It you want to use a local package in a sibling folder for get about the `-e` flag, just do `pip install /path/to/package` and then everything should work

Comment: ok but then how do you install it on another computer after you pull requirements.txt from repository